# Create multiple words from one word by removing one character in every iteration by keeping first and last characters same for every word using mysql

Tags: mysql

Can someone please let me know if there is a way to split the below input word into multiple words by removing one character in every iteration and keeping first and last characters same for every word using mysql? Thank you very much in advance.

Input: awesome

Output: aesome
        awsome
        aweome
        awesme
        awesoe

Thanks,
Raj.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: This isn't really what MySQL is good at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to do iterations in MySQL. You need to create a table that contains all the repetition numbers, and join with that.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    n INT
);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(word, n), SUBSTR(word, n+2)) AS new_word
FROM (SELECT 'awesome' AS word) word_table
JOIN (SELECT n FROM numbers
      WHERE n < LENGTH('awesome')-1) AS numbers
```